# python website development

Tags: python, frameworks, web, wsgi

I need to create a simple website, the server is gonna running on Amazon EC2 web service. But I haven't done web development before.  It seems like I need to learn a lot of stuff, javascript, html, css, web framework, WSGI, apache web server, etc.  And I am confused by some stuff that seems much the same.

So first question, Can anyone tell me what exactly do I need to set the website up. Is a web framework the only thing I need on the server side?

2th question, I am gonna use python on server side, there are really a bunch of web frameworks for python. What's the difference between apache http server and the built-in wsgi or http web servers in those web frameworks.

3th question, Is WSGI the best choice? Most web frameworks support WSGI, does it mean WSGI is built in the web frameworks? Or I need to include mod_wsgi or something alike.

Also, according to [this benchmark of python WSGI servers](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers), [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) and mod_wsgi show great performance with low memory footprint. They don't claim themselves as web frameworks, what's the difference between them and the web frameworks like cherrypy, web2py.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Depends on your website - if you only need static content, you can use static site generators ([Blogofile](http://www.blogofile.com/), [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde) to name a few written in Python) or, if your website serves dynamic content, you should use some kind of framework ([Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), Django, etc). With static site generators all you need on the server is the webserver that serves your content, but with dynamic sites you might need extra libraries for various things like database support, caching, etc.
2. The built-in webservers are usually meant for local development and are generally not suitable for production use. For latter use the specific apps like mod_wsgi (for Apache) or uwsgi (for Nginx) instead. But try to avoid mod_python!
3. WSGI stands for Web Server Gateway Interface and is a standard protocol used between web server and web application (or framework). WSGI seems to be currently the only standard choice, so go with it.

> Also, according to this benchmark of python WSGI servers, gevent and
>   mod_wsgi show great performance with low memory footprint. They don't
>   claim themselves as web frameworks, what's the difference between them
>   and the web frameworks like cherrypy, web2py.

As said before, WSGI is just a way that web server talks with web application. CherryPy and web2py deal with templating, request and session handling and output this information via WSGI to the web server.

And if you worry about the speed, then don't worry about it too much..  :)

Comment: Thank you. The website needs to serve dynamic content. If I get it right, the frameworks are used for developing web application, and mod_wsgi is used in the server to communicate between apps and server, right?

Comment: Yes, though mod_wsgi is only Apache specific.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need the web server, Apache is one popular choice. You will probably also need to install Database, MySQL is free, easy and popular.
2. The most popular (and best in my opinion) python framework is [Django](http://djangoproject.com/).
3. Many run Django with apache using [mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/). Frameworks usually only provide development server that is not suitable to be a real server.
4. The WSGI servers probably only offer request handling and entry points for writing the code, but frameworks offer much more (user handling, admin interface, ORM, templating, etc...).

Comment: No-one should be running anything with mod_python. It's officially depreceated.

Comment: Thank's for the correction, meaned mod_wsgi.

Comment: @Lycha Thank you. Django seems too complicated, and I actually don't need a powerful database support, the server only needs to maintain users' information, and a lock table currently. Data is gonna be stored in amazon S3.

Answer (score 1):

WSGI is an interface. It requires a container (e.g. mod_wsgi), an application (e.g. Django), and optional middleware. Applications can be built directly against WSGI, or they can be built on top of frameworks such as Django that handle the WSGI bit for you.

Don't use the built-in web server in the frameworks. They aren't usually designed for performance, and they usually don't integrate well with the non-WSGI parts of your server.

Comment: @lgnacio So I need a web server, a database, and mod_wsgi on the server side. For developing application on client-side, a framework is enough to get started. right?

Comment: The database is optional, unless you're developing a database-oriented application. If the framework has a built-in webserver then it *could* be enough, but you may need to look into a separate WSGI container.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a programming question, since you're really just asking how to get started with web development, and there is no clear answer to this.

I can warmly recommend getting started with Django, simply because it is very well documented and has great tutorials. It also uses Python which means it is easier to understand other people's code.

Regardless of whether you choose Django or something else, just choose a web application development tutorial and run through it. Google for one (for Django you can ask on the very helpful #django IRC channel). That should give you a good basis with at least one working example which you understand, as well as a clear picture of what the different pieces of a running web application are and how they work together.

Afterwards you can branch off and learn many various relevant skills and technologies, preferably driven by your needs as you develop an actual web application of your own (even if just for learning purposes at first).

Good luck!